# Angular guard not being invoked when navigating back to application after sign out redirect

Tags: angular, openid-connect

My Angular (v13.3.11) application uses a guard on all main routes to verify that a user is logged in.

When the user signs out, they are redirected to an OpenID Connect end session endpoint, and then redirected back to my application's sign out page.

The issue is:

After signing out and being redirected to the sign out page, clicking the browser back button allows the user to navigate back to the previous page (where ever they were before sign out).

The authentication guard's canActivate method is not being invoked at all, along with any other Angular lifecycle methods (ngOnInit, ngOnDestroy, etc.). Therefore the user is able to perform actions on the page. It seems like the application is in a cached state of some sort.

This only happens in the Angular production build (v13.3.11), and mainly in Chrome incognito. I can replicate this in other browsers, but you have to time the browser back button click perfectly.

Thanks all, this issue has me stumped. Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runGuardsAndResolvers` parameter on routes to force recalculate your guards and resolvers. Example:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [
       ....
    ]
  }
]
```